# Extract string from multiple log files in different folders

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have a lot of subfolders in a parent folder and inside each subfolder, there is a log file. Inside the log file I have a lot of data like this:

```
>  Rotational constants (GHZ):           0.0423083           0.0029364  
> 0.0027927  Standard basis: 6-31G(d,p) (6D, 7F)  There are  1566 symmetry adapted cartesian basis functions of A   symmetry.  There are
> 1566 symmetry adapted basis functions of A   symmetry.   1566 basis
> functions,  3052 primitive gaussians,  1566 cartesian basis functions 
> 355 alpha electrons      355 beta electrons
>        nuclear repulsion energy     15971.0567247177 Hartrees.  NAtoms=  130 NActive=  130 NUniq=  130 SFac= 1.00D+00 NAtFMM=   60
> NAOKFM=T Big=T  Integral buffers will be    131072 words long. 
> Raffenetti 2 integral format.  Two-electron integral symmetry is
> turned on.  One-electron integrals computed using PRISM.  NBasis= 
> 1566 RedAO= T EigKep=  2.31D-04  NBF=  1566  NBsUse=  1566 1.00D-06
> EigRej= -1.00D+00 NBFU=  1566  Initial guess from the checkpoint file:
>     > 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
>          Rot=    1.000000   -0.000006    0.000001   -0.000001 Ang=   0.00 deg.  Requested convergence on RMS density matrix=1.00D-08 within 128 cycles.  Requested convergence on MAX density matrix=1.00D-06. 
> Requested convergence on             energy=1.00D-06.  No special
> actions if energy rises.  SCF Done:  E(RB3LYP) =  -8526.66394979    
> A.U. after    6 cycles
>             NFock=  6  Conv=0.72D-08     -V/T= 2.0055  Calling FoFJK, ICntrl=      2127 FMM=T ISym2X=0 I1Cent= 0 IOpClX= 0 NMat=1 NMatS=1
> NMatT=0.
```

As an example, I am looking for `SCF Done:  E(RB3LYP) =  -8526.66394979` in the abovementioned text. the value after the `=` changes in each file. What I need is to extract all the values and put them in a text file in the parent folder. For example, I have 3 folders: bar, baz, and foo. Now I need the following result:

```
bar : -8526.66394979
baz : -112232.123391
foo : 12312313:34574
```

After running the following script, I will have only one value (i.e -8526.66394979). Could you please help me to fix the problem?

```
#!/bin/bash

for file_name in *
do

cd $file_name

EE=$(grep -i 'scf done' *.log | tail -1 | awk 'NR==1 {print $5}')

echo "Electronic Energy : $EE" | column -t -s ":"  > ${file_name%%.*}.txt

mv ${file_name%%.*}.txt ../

done
```

Comment: What problem? How does this fail? It is needlessly complcated for what I think you need, but since you don't tell us how it fails, or show us anything about the directories and files you need to process it is hard to know. Can you please [edit] your question and i) show us the directory structure and ii) some example files, iii) tell us how this failed and, most importantly, iv) show us the output you expect.

Comment: For instance, your script is only keeping the last value from the last file. Is that what you want or do you want the last value from _each_ file?

Comment: I have tried to elaborate on what I need. your code is very good but it saves the values in different .txt files. I need only one .txt file in the parent folder. Thank you so much for your attention.

Comment: Oh. OK, your code did the same thing, that's why I did it that way. Do you also need that last occurrence of scf done in each file? Can there be more than one or do all your files just have one `scf done`?

Comment: Thank you for answering. I prepared the following code:
#!/bin/bash



for dir in */; do
    grep -i 'scf done' "$dir"/*.log | 
         awk 'END{print ""$5}'|
            column -t -s ":" > "${dir///}".tmp
done


for file_name in *.tmp
 do
    echo "${file_name%%.*} : " 
 cat "$file_name"  
   
    
done > tmp


awk 'NR%2{printf "%s ",$0;next;}1' tmp > tmp2
        sort -k 3 tmp2 > Energy.txt

rm *.tmp tmp tmp2
cat Energy.txt

It does work! But rather stupid. Can we convert it to a more efficient script using advanced commands?

Comment: Please edit your question to add clarifications, it is impossible to read in the comments. But please answer my other questions first: are there many occurrences of the search string in each file or just one?

Comment: I have posted an answer to my question and it shows the script clearly. Yes, there are many "scf done" in each file and I need the last one in the studied file. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one log file in each directory and you want to keep the last value from that log file and store it in a text file whose name is the name of the directory, you can do something like this:

```
for dir in */; do
    grep -i 'scf done' "$dir"/*.log | 
        awk 'END{print "Electronic Energy : "$5}' |
            column -t -s ":" > "${dir///}".txt
done
```

For example, I used the following setup:

```
$ tree
.
├── dir1
│   └── file.log
├── dir10
│   └── file.log
├── dir2
│   └── file.log
├── dir3
│   └── file.log
├── dir4
│   └── file.log
├── dir5
│   └── file.log
├── dir6
│   └── file.log
├── dir7
│   └── file.log
├── dir8
│   └── file.log
└── dir9
    └── file.log
```

Each `file.log` contained this:

```
$ cat dir1/file.log 
a b scf done 123
```

Running the `for` loop above resulted in:

```
$ ls *txt
dir10.txt  dir1.txt  dir2.txt  dir3.txt  dir4.txt  dir5.txt  dir6.txt  dir7.txt  dir8.txt  dir9.txt
```

Each of which contained:

```
$ cat dir1.txt 
Electronic Energy    123
```

If that doesn't work for you, please update your question and show us the relevant directory structure, file names, example input and expected output.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I prepared this one:

```
#!/bin/bash



for dir in */; do
    grep -i 'scf done' "$dir"/*.log | 
         awk 'END{print ""$5}'|
            column -t -s ":" > "${dir///}".tmp
done


for file_name in *.tmp
 do
    echo "${file_name%%.*} : " 
    cat "$file_name"    
      
    
done > tmp


awk 'NR%2{printf "%s ",$0;next;}1' tmp > tmp2
        sort -k 3 tmp2 > Energy.txt

rm *.tmp tmp tmp2
cat Energy.txt
```

It works and covers all the things that I need. However; I am looking for an advanced way of coding by using probably efficient commands.

Comment: Is this an answer or a new question?

Comment: It is an answer but it is not beautiful. I think it requests an advanced way of coding.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping I understood (and reproduced) your directory structure correctly, try this:

```
awk '/SCF Done/ {print FILENAME ": " $NF}' */*.log
bar/b1.log: -8526.66394979
baz/b2.log: -7777777.22222
baz/b2.log: -112232.123391
foo/f3.log: -7777777.22222
foo/f3.log: 12312313.34574
```

If you need the directory only, `split` the `FILENAME` and use the first element of the resulting array. If you need the last entry in every file only, try

```
awk '/SCF Done/ {print FILENAME ": " $NF}' */*.log | tac | sort -u -k1,1
bar/b1.log: -8526.66394979
baz/b2.log: -112232.123391
foo/f3.log: 12312313.34574
```

which is easier and more straightforward than arranging it in `awk`.

Comment: It is better but there are some errors. First We need to use $5 instead of &NF.

bar/bar.log should change to "bar" only

And this script extracts all scf done in all files. We need only the last scf done in each file.

Comment: So the sample in your question, where the desired number IS $NF, does not represent your real world data? And, did you read the remarks in the post?

Comment: I don't know the meaning of splitting the file name! Sorry I am absolutely neophite.